# Is the trapezoid method of integration important?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm not sure if this is the right place for this question, but I'll ask it anyways.

I'm learning different integration techniques - trig substitution, integration by parts etc. Then, after all that, I'm taught the trapezoid method (Simpson's Rule). Why is it necessary to learn the trapezoid method after learning all the others?

Comment: The trapezium rule (like Simpson's rule) is a method of *numerical* integration.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown true, but so what?

Comment: How else do you know to integrate $\int_0^1 \sin{(x^2)}\mathrm{d}x$ for example?

Comment: @PeterForeman There are myriads of ways to compute that without the trapezoidal rule. So, they can still ask 'so what?'

Comment: @PeterForeman use double angle

Comment: Many more examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonelementary_integral

Comment: Also, it's $\sin(x^2)$, not $\sin(2x)$.

Comment: Numerical integration is important, because we often need to approximate integrals whose values we can't explicitly compute. The trapezoidal rule and Simpson's rule are too weak to find much practical use (unless you want to approximate an integral by hand), but they serve as important motivating examples to develop quadrature methods.

Comment: The point is that the trapezoidal rule is the basis for many other numerical methods. As a foundational knowledge it is important to at least be aware of it, and perhaps have a grasp of how it could be used in other methods. Like other things, it is possible that you never need it.